# AJAX Actionlink works but my AJAX in jquery doesnt? (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an @Ajax.ActionLink that I am using to delete a record form my database.  When I click the link, my page asks for a confirmation, deletes the course, and refreshes the div that contains the table of records.  I want to use AJAX in jquery instead of using the action link.  When I click my delete button, I get my confirmation box, click ok and then nothing happens.  I know my jquery function is getting the correct values from the row selected because I had them output to make sure.  I can't figure out why the ajax never runs but the action link works fine.  Below is my code for both and my controller

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult deleteCourses(string stuId, string courseAbNum)
    {
        KuPlanEntities db = new KuPlanEntities();
            var deleteCourse = (from course in db.COURSE_TAKEN
                                where course.courseAbNum == courseAbNum && course.Id == stuId
                                select course);

                foreach (var course in deleteCourse)
                {
                    db.COURSE_TAKEN.Remove(course);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }


            var stuCourses = (from studCourse in db.COURSE_TAKEN
                              join course in db.COURSEs on studCourse.courseAbNum equals course.courseAbNum
                              where studCourse.Id == stuId
                              select new courseTakenView { Id = studCourse.Id, courseAbNum = studCourse.courseAbNum, status = studCourse.status, grade = studCourse.grade, courseDesc = course.courseDesc, credits = course.credits, rowNum = studCourse.rowNum });

            var model = new courseListViewModel
            {
                userId = stuId,
                courseTaken = stuCourses
            };

        return PartialView("~/Views/ManageStudentCourses/listCourseRefresh.cshtml",model);
    }
```

Action link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "deleteCourses", new { stuId = Model.userId, courseAbNum = @course.courseAbNum }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "refreshList", Confirm = ("Are you sure you want to delete this course?") })
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.deleteCourseBtn').click(function () {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this course?"))
    {
        var courseAbNum = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var stuId = $('#userId').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ManageStudentCourses/deleteCourses',
            data: { stuId:stuId, courseAbNum:courseAbNum },
            dataType:  'html'
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#refreshList').html(result);
            })
        });

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
})
```

});

Comment: Did you check your browser console for errors or to see that whether the request looks like it should?

Comment: it says Uncaught TypeError:  undefined is not a function.  The ".success(function (result) { "line is highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off. You're trying to call `'html'.success(...)`. I would do this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ManageStudentCourses/deleteCourses',
        data: { stuId:stuId, courseAbNum:courseAbNum },
        dataType:  'html'
    }).done(function (result) {
        $('#refreshList').html(result);
    });
```

Comment: or `}).success(function(data){//do stuff});`

Comment: @Sebastien `jqXHR.success()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: your right .success() is deprecated, is .ajax({success:function(data){//do stuff}}) also deprecated or are those two completly differente I looked at your link and it didn't clearly state if the two were deprecated